# How is it possible in Meteor to publish only selected keys of a MongoDB document?

Tags: mongodb, object, meteor

Hello my question is if i have a nth document of monogDb like

```
{
  "_id" : "PfZ6pn2qrXyHk53sz",
  "type" : "manager",
  "dob" : ISODate("1980-02-02T18:30:00.000Z"),
  "registration" : 1231231231,
  "country_code" : "India",
  "username" : "asad",
  "global_is_active" : true,
  "gender" : "male",
  "user_photo" : "photo",
  "user_creation_ip" : "demo ip",
  "is_deleted" : false,
  "privileges" : {
    "partner" : {},
    "consumer" : {}
  },
  "following" : {
    "users" : [],
    "partners" : []
  },
  "followers" : [],
  "blogger_info" : {},
  "user_verified" : false
}
```

and when i publish document publish with limited keys like

```
{
 "_id" : "PfZ6pn2qrXyHk53sz",
 "type" : "manager",
 "user_photo" : "photo",
 "privileges" : {
   "partner" : {},
   "consumer" : {}
  },
 "following" : {
   "users" : [],
   "partners" : []
 },
 "followers" : []
}
```

when client subscribe the collection get only these keys..

Thank's in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since a publication of a MongoDB is just the result of a query, you can adjust the query accordingly. Instead of

```
Meteor.publish("rooms", function () {
  return Rooms.find({});
});
```

which would publish all documents from the Rooms collection, you can change the query to something like this:

```
Meteor.publish("rooms", function () {
  return Rooms.find({}, {fields: {secretInfo: 0}});
});
```

This instruction tells MongoDB / Meteor to publish all fields except the `secretInfo` field of the collection.

Also see the [Meteor documentation for the publish method](http://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html#Meteor-publish).